# How to set AWS credentials for user www-data for Django app using NGINX

Tags: django, environment-variables, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-iot

I have a Django app running on a Linux server under NGINX. The "user" for the Django app is `www-data`. In this app, I try to connect to AWS IOT, and to do that I believe that the AWS boto3 package tries to find the AWS credentials here: `~/.aws/credentials`. The problem is that for the user `www-data` there is no such path! When I login to the server (using my real username), and I try to run a script that connects to AWS, it connects just fine. Let's say my username is "joe". There is indeed a file `/home/joe/.aws/credentials` that contains the correct credentials. This is why the script works fine when I run as user "joe". But when the Django app is running, it doesn't work because there is no login user www-data, ie there is no file `/home/www-data/.aws/credentials.`

I understand that AWS boto3 let's us set an environment variable to specify a non-standard path to the credentials file. This env variable is `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` and there is also a AWS_CONFIG_FILE.

However, I don't know how to set an environment variable in Django for user `www-data` so that boto3 can now use that environment variable to specify the AWS credentials path.

Anyone know how to do this? Note that this is a production environment so I can't use any local server tricks/hacks.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/qnub/django-boto

Comment: Log into to your server. Switch to root `su root`. `mkdir /root/.aws`. From your home directory `cp .aws /root/.aws`. Now the credentials are in the correct location for a service. Usually a Linux service runs as the user `root`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your Django App from an EC2 instances the best practice is associate an IAM Role to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue but in a docker container and with apache instead of NGINX. For the container, we can do the following:

- Edit /etc/apache2/envvars where environment settings for apache live:

  `echo "export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/root/.aws/credentials" >> /etc/apache2/envvars`
- change ownership of aws credentials file parent directory:

  `chown -R www-data:www-data /root`
- restart
  apache:

  `service apache2 restart`

Note that here ownership of root's home directory was changed. This is because aws needs certain file permissions and ownership for the credentials file (which means only www-data will be able to use this login from now on.) Maybe it would be a better practice (especially if you're runnning on an actual machine and not a container) to copy the credentials file to a new location and follow the same steps:

```
mkdir -p /home/joe/workdir/.aws/
cp /home/joe/.aws/credentials /home/joe/foo/.aws/credentials
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data home/joe/foo/
sudo echo "export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/home/joe/foo/.aws/credentials" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I don't know how well this fits to the NGINX config, but hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I don't think it is a safe/good idea to change the ownership of the `/root` directory. Can't you save the credentials in another location and point `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` to there?